# A set $S=\{v_1, v_2,....,v_n\}$ is linearly independent and a vector $v_i$ is removed from the set. Is the new set still linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

This seems trivial I just can't think of a formal proof for it. I was thinking of using the contrapositive, which would be:

If a set of vectors S is linearly dependent and a vector v is added to the set. Is S still linearly dependent?

But I'm not even sure how to prove that! My definition of linear combinations, span, and linear combinations have all been in sigma notation if that makes any difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Write out the definition of linear independence for both sets and compare them.

Comment: Suppose you had a dependency in the smaller set.  Then....

Comment: as one of the definitions is that none of the vectors can be represented as sum of the others (the sigma notation), so yes, you can remove and it still be linearly independent for all the others. (You can write proof by contradiction if you want)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes the set is still linearly independent.

Assume that missing vector is $v_n$ and let $$\lambda _1v_1 + \lambda _2v_2+....+\lambda _{n-1}v_{n-1} =0$$

You need to show $$ \lambda _1 = \lambda _2 =...= \lambda _{n-1} =0$$

Consider the linear combination $$\lambda _1v_1 + \lambda _2v_2+....+\lambda _{n-1}v_{n-1} +0v_n=0$$

Since $$v_1,v_2,...,v_n$$ are linearly independent we have $$ \lambda _1 = \lambda _2 =...= \lambda _{n-1} = \lambda _n  =0$$

Which implies $$ \lambda _1 = \lambda _2 =...= \lambda _{n-1} =0$$

Thus the new set is also linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! That makes perfect sense. I was thinking too much about a case where the set of vectors magically becomes linearly dependent once it loses a vector, rather than the nature of the scalars themselves. Thanks!

Comment: @TyJensen You are most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Without loss of generality, suppose that $i=1$.

Suppose instead that $\{v_2,v_3,\dots,v_n\}$ were linearly *dependent*.

Then there are some scalars $c_2,c_3,\dots,c_n$ with at least one $c_j\neq 0$ such that

$$c_2v_2+c_3v_3+\dots+c_nv_n = 0$$

But then using these same values of $c_2,\dots,c_n$ and letting $c_1=0$ we would still have the same $c_j\neq 0$ and we would also have

$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\dots+c_nv_n=0$$

Thus, $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ would be linearly dependent as well.  This proves the original claim by contraposition.